# CSS rule being overwritten

Tags: css

For some reason my "a:link" rule is overwriting a specific rule applied to a link.

```
a:link  {color: red  ;}
.button {color: white; background: red;}

<a class="button" href="blah.com">Hello</a>
```

The end result is that the link shown above has red text and a red background, whereas I want the colour to be white as specified in the .button rule

I have the feeling that I'm doing something wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: try .button {color: white !important; background: red;}

Answer (score 1):

The `a:link` selector has a higher [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than `.button`, so for elements where both apply (as in your example) the former takes precedence, making the text red.

If you know that buttons are going to contain links a lot of the time, you can simply style those links explicitly:

```
a:link  {color: red  ;}
.button, a.button:link {color: white; background: red;}
```

Alternatively, you can artificially increase the specificity of the `.button` selector so that it's at least equal to that of `a:link`:

```
a:link  {color: red  ;}
html .button {color: white; background: red;}
```

**I would not recommend this solution as it is quite brittle and it's not immediately apparent that the seemingly redundant `html` part does play an important role.**

Another possible solution would be to use `!important`, although I would also avoid that especially since there is a perfectly good alternative that doesn't use the nukes.

Comment: The idea is correct, but I think that the example is not correct. it should be a.button:link instead of .button a:link. It is not a link inside a button, it is an a of class button

Comment: If the button should change color regardless of its visited state, and there is an `a:visited` rule somewhere, use `a.button` and make sure that rule comes last instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the second rule to:

```
.button {color: white !important; background: red;}
```

Note the `!important`, it makes that rule automatically have higher priority.

Comment: I know I can use '!important' but that's doesn't seem like the semantic solution... there's an error in my code. I'm sure people do this all the time without using '!important'

Comment: Try making sure the `.button` rule is *after* the `a:link` rule in your CSS. But `!important` is OK for this situation, because you are trying to override another rule. That's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a:link` is more specific than `.button`. More specific rules in CSS always override less specific ones.

You can either (a) add !important to the colour declaration like this...

```
.button {color: white !important; background: red;}
```

... Or (b) make the `.button` selector more specific, like this...

```
a.button {color: white; background: red;}
```

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ykHVa/

Personally I'd prefer (b) over (a), since `!important` can make CSS a nightmare to debug over time.

Answer (score 0):

A rule with :link will only be overruled by another rule with the :link following it.  You need a rule thats equally specific.

```
a:link  {color: red  ;}
.button,.button:link {color: white; background: red;}
```

You can also use !important as other answerers have pointed out.  But that's not ideal, as it can make it confusing when you try to add new rules later.

http://jsfiddle.net/PNxPf/